# data-callback function not working in Invisible reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, invisible-recaptcha

I have implemented Invisible reCAPTCHA in a site for a register form.When I click the the submit button the reCAPTCHA will appear and after the verification it doesn't call the callback function.
This is the script.

Scripts

```
 {literal}
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
 <script>
 function onSuccess = function(token) {
 document.getElementById("registerform").submit();
 }
 </script>
{/literal}
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" name="registerform" id="registerform" onsubmit="javascript: return checkRegFormFields(this);">
<td colspan="2" class="button-row">
<button class="btn main-button btn-danger no-bdrs btn-block btn-lg g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekey" data-callback="onSuccess"  title="Submit">  Submit </button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you might have two things happening here.

1) Either your callback is not registered when you click on submit button.

order your script with callback first and then recaptcha api in html as below -

(for reference: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#explicit_render)

```
{literal}
 <script>
 function onSuccess = function(token) {
 document.getElementById("registerform").submit();
 }
 </script>
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
{/literal}
```

2) Or if callback is registered then google is detecting you as a bot so data-callback is not getting invoked , then in this case you must be getting a captcha image challenge.

data-callback is invoked  only if you are validated successfully.

Hope this helps..